# SQL query to convert date wise transactions into month and year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables: **Transaction** and **A/C_Detail**.

Columns in the table **Transaction** are:

**A/C No, Transaction_Amt, Tran_Type, Transaction Date, Transaction Time, Location, Mode.**

Note: Tran_Type field may have values CR/DR  to represent credit/debit.

Columns in the table **A/C_Detail** are:

**A/C No, A/C Holder_Name, Gender, DOB**

I need to write a SQL query to get the following fields in the output:

**A/C No, A/C Holder_Name, Transaction_Amt, Year, Month**

Can someone please help me with the SQL query for the desired output?

Comment: Sql server is Oracle server

Answer (score 0):

Considering A/C no is the common field in both the tables,in that case u can use following query(I'm using same column name for understanding purpose):
Assumed that debit amount will be -ve in data and credited will be +ve amount.

```
Select
    a.A/C No, 
    b.A/C Holder_Name, 
    sum(a.Transaction_Amt), 
    to_char(a.Transaction Date,'YYYY')Year,
    to_char(a.Transaction Date,'Mon')Month
    from Transaction a,A/C_Detail b
    where a.A/C No=b.A/C No
    group by a.A/C No, 
    b.A/C Holder_Name,
    to_char(a.Transaction Date,'YYYY'),
    to_char(a.Transaction Date,'Mon');
```

Comment: Hi Smau, I believe this will give me ttransaction details correponding and their month and year. But I require the view of transaction details that happened in a month in an year. i.e. for example  if an a/c XXX shows 200 as debit and 300 as credit on 2nd and 3rd Jan 2015 it should give the output as   XXX  100 2015 Jan.

Comment: @darin Required changes have been made, pls note.